Are there convex polyhedrons with isosceles triangular faces that are also mutually non-congruent?
The main question here has received a nice and simple answer. There are further questions below which could still be of interest.
Question: For $n$ a positive even integer, is it possible to form a convex polyhedron with $n$ faces, all triangular, such that the faces are all isosceles and also pair-wise non-congruent? For which values of $n$ is such a polyhedron possible, if at all? No other constraints.
Note 1: For $n$ odd, we cannot form a polyhedron with $n$ faces, all triangular.
Note 2: Further questions can be asked on forming convex $n$-hedrons with $n$ mutually non-congruent triangular faces such that (1) all faces also have same area (such a tetrahedron could be constructed by intersecting 3 cylinders with axes coincident with the three sides of a triangle but not sure about higher $n$) OR (2) all faces have same perimeter (one might be able to achieve such a tet by intersecting 3 ellipsoids).
Note 3: Yet another variant is:  to form convex $n$-hedrons with $n$ mutually non-congruent faces that are all right triangles. I could do it for $n$ = 4 and 6 but couldn't see an easy generalization to higher $n$.
An earlier question: Convex polyhedra with non-congruent faces

Take the convex hull of these $n/2+2$ points: any $n/2$ points on the unit circle in the $xy$ plane such that consecutive distances are pairwise distinct; two points on the $z$ axis, one positive, one negative, with any values except for a finite set of exceptions where coincidental congruences happen.

That is neat and simple. Thanks! Hope the questions mentioned in 'note 2' are of some interest as well.

Here is a construction for $n=6k$ (with $k\ge 2$).
Take any polyhedron with $2k$ triangular faces and edges of pairwise distincts length. For any triangular face, the locus of points at equal distance from the three vertices is a line, take a point at random on this line, close to the face, and add it as a new vertex. Doing so, you replace each face by three isosceles triangular faces (which are not pairwise congruent, as the “old” edges have distincts length). “New” faces coming from different “old” faces have sides of independent random length, so are not congruent with probability one.
One can probably extend the construction for all even $n\ge 6$ (starting from a polyhedron which already has some isosceles faces), but not for $n=4$ (if I’m not missing something).

Nice! Hope the questions listed following the main one above are more interesting. Marking the question as answered.
